# Is there a way to use unaltered Street View images from Google Maps in a travel blog that runs AdSense ads?

Tags: google-maps, google-adsense, street-view

I use my own photos in my blog most of the time. Now and then, though, I feel I need to provide my readers with a reference point.

Ideally, this is how I would do this:

I'd take a snapshot of a Street View image found on Google Maps - of, say, a certain fountain in Rome. Then I'd draw an arrow on the resulting photo, and add some text next to it, such as "Passing to the right of this fountain will get you to the steps leading to the top of the hill I mentioned earlier."

I would leave all the Google signs in.

Would Google find this objectionable?

Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Have you already read the terms and conditions of the service that is the source of the images?

Comment: @Rubén Yes, I have. Twice. It's remarkably confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Everything you need to know is in here:   https://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines/

I'm not able to provide any legal interprestation - but note this paragraph - bolding mine.

> Note that if you (a) **embed** a classic map, Street View panorama, or My
>   Map; (b) use one of our APIs on the web or in an application; or (c)
>   use Google Earth Pro, or Earth Studio on desktop; then the necessary
>   attribution is already baked into the map and no further credit is
>   needed.

Comment: So, according to the link you've provided, and the portion you've quoted, would it be all right to include in a blog running Adsense something like the photo (from Street View) I just added to the post? 'Cause I'm really confused here.